# Unable to run example code using Quantlib on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, quantlib

My mac version is 10.11.5 (El Capitan) and I had no issue in running C++11 in terminal.

I followed exactly the guideline as shown in the quantlib official webpage: http://quantlib.org/install/macosx.shtml (I used macport to install boost 1.59.0 and downloaded quantlib v1.8 from [quantlib.org](http://quantlib.org))

However, when I tried to run the example code:

```
cd Examples/BermudanSwaption
g++ -I/opt/local/include/ -I/opt/local/include/boost BermudanSwaption.cpp -o bermudanswaption -L/opt/local/lib/ -lQuantLib
```

as suggested by the guideline, I encountered a long list of error message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QuantLib::MultiStepSwap::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepSwap in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::ExerciseAdapter::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::ExerciseAdapter in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::OneStepForwards::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::OneStepForwards in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::BermudanExercise::BermudanExercise(std::__1::vector<QuantLib::Date, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::Date> > const&, bool)", referenced from:
      _main in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepNothing::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepNothing in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepRatchet::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepRatchet in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepForwards::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepForwards in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepSwaption::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepSwaption in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::OneStepOptionlets::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::OneStepOptionlets in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepOptionlets::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepOptionlets in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::OneStepCoinitialSwaps::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::OneStepCoinitialSwaps in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::OneStepCoterminalSwaps::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::OneStepCoterminalSwaps in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepCoinitialSwaps::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepCoinitialSwaps in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepInverseFloater::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepInverseFloater in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepCoterminalSwaps::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepCoterminalSwaps in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepCoterminalSwaptions::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepCoterminalSwaptions in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::MultiStepPeriodCapletSwaptions::nextTimeStep(QuantLib::CurveState const&, std::__1::vector<unsigned long, std::__1::allocator<unsigned long> >&, std::__1::vector<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> >, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::vector<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow, std::__1::allocator<QuantLib::MarketModelMultiProduct::CashFlow> > > >&)", referenced from:
      vtable for QuantLib::MultiStepPeriodCapletSwaptions in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::Error::Error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, long, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      QuantLib::DiscretizedOption::reset(unsigned long) in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      QuantLib::Instrument::setupArguments(QuantLib::PricingEngine::arguments*) const in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      QuantLib::Option::setupArguments(QuantLib::PricingEngine::arguments*) const in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      QuantLib::Payoff::accept(QuantLib::AcyclicVisitor&) in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      QuantLib::SimpleQuote::value() const in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      QuantLib::BlackVolTermStructure::accept(QuantLib::AcyclicVisitor&) in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      QuantLib::Handle<QuantLib::Quote>::operator->() const in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      ...
  "QuantLib::detail::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, QuantLib::detail::percent_holder const&)", referenced from:
      calibrateModel(boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::ShortRateModel> const&, std::__1::vector<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::CalibrationHelper>, std::__1::allocator<boost::shared_ptr<QuantLib::CalibrationHelper> > > const&) in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
      _main in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
  "QuantLib::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, QuantLib::Date const&)", referenced from:
      QuantLib::InterestRateIndex::valueDate(QuantLib::Date const&) const in BermudanSwaption-032f83.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have no idea what's going on. Can anyone help me to understand how shall I fix it?

Many thanks!

Per Mark's suggestion, the directory listing in /opt/local is:

```
total 421544
drwxr-xr-x  12 root  admin       408 Jun 16 22:05 db48
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  admin       476 Jun 16 22:05 engines
drwxr-xr-x   7 root  admin       238 Jun 16 22:05 gettext
drwxr-xr-x   6 root  admin       204 Jun 16 22:05 icu
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin  34927800 Jun 17 00:03 libQuantLib.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  73890632 Jun 17 00:03 libQuantLib.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jun 17 00:03 libQuantLib.dylib -> libQuantLib.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin       975 Jun 17 00:03 libQuantLib.la
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     13740 Jun 16 06:43 libasprintf.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin      3952 Jun 16 06:43 libasprintf.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jun 16 06:43 libasprintf.dylib -> libasprintf.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     10144 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_atomic-mt.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    263712 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_chrono-mt.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     25784 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_chrono-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     60520 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_container-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     54368 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_context-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     63796 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_coroutine-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     76456 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_date_time-mt.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin      3832 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_exception-mt.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    123140 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    502616 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_graph-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    155336 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_iostreams-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1114060 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_locale-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1244756 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_log-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1651560 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_log_setup-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    162264 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_math_c99-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    117984 Jan 30 01:22 libboost_math_c99f-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    125540 Jan 30 01:22 libboost_math_c99l-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    660412 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_math_tr1-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    671312 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_math_tr1f-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    645256 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_math_tr1l-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     71040 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_prg_exec_monitor-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    630380 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_program_options-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    441572 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_python-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     38224 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_random-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1355040 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_regex-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    572924 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_serialization-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    123452 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_signals-mt.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     82200 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_system-mt.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     25148 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_system-mt.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin  11787512 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_test_exec_monitor-mt.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    152956 Jan 30 01:20 libboost_thread-mt.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    256272 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_timer-mt.a
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     48504 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_timer-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1014044 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   2336956 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_wave-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    423044 Jan 30 01:21 libboost_wserialization-mt.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     77960 Jan 29 16:21 libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:21 libbz2.1.0.dylib -> libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:21 libbz2.1.dylib -> libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    184472 Jan 29 16:21 libbz2.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:21 libbz2.dylib -> libbz2.1.0.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin      9088 Jan 29 16:15 libcharset.1.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin      3720 Jan 29 16:15 libcharset.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:15 libcharset.dylib -> libcharset.1.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  admin   2048916 May  3 13:08 libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   3372840 May  3 13:08 libcrypto.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 May  3 13:08 libcrypto.dylib -> libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        12 Jan 29 16:15 libcurses.a -> libncurses.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:15 libcurses.dylib -> libncurses.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    171984 Jan 29 20:46 libedit.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    260032 Jan 29 20:46 libedit.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 20:46 libedit.dylib -> libedit.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    129924 May 17 17:25 libexpat.1.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    158128 May 17 17:25 libexpat.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 May 17 17:25 libexpat.dylib -> libexpat.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     58792 Jan 29 16:15 libform.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    100680 Jan 29 16:15 libform.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 16:15 libform.dylib -> libform.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 16:15 libformw.6.dylib -> libform.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin         9 Jan 29 16:15 libformw.a -> libform.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 16:15 libformw.dylib -> libform.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1477476 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextlib-0.19.8.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        28 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextlib.dylib -> libgettextlib-0.19.8.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    325504 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextpo.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    515768 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextpo.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextpo.dylib -> libgettextpo.0.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    276312 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextsrc-0.19.8.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        28 Jun 16 06:43 libgettextsrc.dylib -> libgettextsrc-0.19.8.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jan 30 01:35 libhistory.6.2.dylib -> libhistory.6.3.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  admin     35264 Jan 30 01:35 libhistory.6.3.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jan 30 01:35 libhistory.6.dylib -> libhistory.6.3.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     41336 Jan 30 01:35 libhistory.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jan 30 01:35 libhistory.dylib -> libhistory.6.3.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   1052104 Jan 29 16:15 libiconv.2.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   1088128 Jan 29 16:15 libiconv.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 Jan 29 16:15 libiconv.dylib -> libiconv.2.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin  25911392 Jan 29 23:00 libicudata.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 29 23:00 libicudata.55.dylib -> libicudata.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin  25909112 Jan 29 22:59 libicudata.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 29 23:00 libicudata.dylib -> libicudata.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   2228116 Jan 29 22:59 libicui18n.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 29 22:59 libicui18n.55.dylib -> libicui18n.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   3840808 Jan 29 22:59 libicui18n.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 29 22:59 libicui18n.dylib -> libicui18n.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     54240 Jan 29 22:59 libicuio.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicuio.55.dylib -> libicuio.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     65984 Jan 29 22:59 libicuio.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicuio.dylib -> libicuio.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    302436 Jan 29 22:59 libicule.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicule.55.dylib -> libicule.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    581304 Jan 29 22:59 libicule.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicule.dylib -> libicule.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     42200 Jan 29 22:59 libiculx.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libiculx.55.dylib -> libiculx.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     59832 Jan 29 22:59 libiculx.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libiculx.dylib -> libiculx.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     57668 Jan 29 22:59 libicutest.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 29 22:59 libicutest.55.dylib -> libicutest.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     76696 Jan 29 22:59 libicutest.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 29 22:59 libicutest.dylib -> libicutest.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    170744 Jan 29 22:59 libicutu.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicutu.55.dylib -> libicutu.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    237424 Jan 29 22:59 libicutu.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicutu.dylib -> libicutu.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   1396828 Jan 29 22:59 libicuuc.55.1.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicuuc.55.dylib -> libicuuc.55.1.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin   2162520 Jan 29 22:59 libicuuc.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        19 Jan 29 22:59 libicuuc.dylib -> libicuuc.55.1.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     54252 Jun 16 06:43 libintl.8.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     72392 Jun 16 06:43 libintl.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jun 16 06:43 libintl.dylib -> libintl.8.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     26556 Jan 29 16:15 libmenu.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     45392 Jan 29 16:15 libmenu.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 16:15 libmenu.dylib -> libmenu.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 16:15 libmenuw.6.dylib -> libmenu.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin         9 Jan 29 16:15 libmenuw.a -> libmenu.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        15 Jan 29 16:15 libmenuw.dylib -> libmenu.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     66060 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses++.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    104160 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses++.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses++.dylib -> libncurses++.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses++w.6.dylib -> libncurses++.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        14 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses++w.a -> libncurses++.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        20 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses++w.dylib -> libncurses++.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    309972 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    542104 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:15 libncurses.dylib -> libncurses.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:15 libncursesw.6.dylib -> libncurses.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        12 Jan 29 16:15 libncursesw.a -> libncurses.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:15 libncursesw.dylib -> libncurses.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     13756 Jan 29 16:15 libpanel.6.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     17200 Jan 29 16:15 libpanel.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 Jan 29 16:15 libpanel.dylib -> libpanel.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 Jan 29 16:15 libpanelw.6.dylib -> libpanel.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        10 Jan 29 16:15 libpanelw.a -> libpanel.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 Jan 29 16:15 libpanelw.dylib -> libpanel.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        66 Mar  1 21:42 libpython2.7.dylib -> /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 30 01:35 libreadline.6.2.dylib -> libreadline.6.3.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  admin    223256 Jan 30 01:35 libreadline.6.3.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 30 01:35 libreadline.6.dylib -> libreadline.6.3.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    377744 Jan 30 01:35 libreadline.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        21 Jan 30 01:35 libreadline.dylib -> libreadline.6.3.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin    871688 May 19 07:05 libsqlite3.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin   1129904 May 19 07:05 libsqlite3.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 May 19 07:05 libsqlite3.dylib -> libsqlite3.0.dylib
-r-xr-xr-x   1 root  admin    388176 May  3 13:08 libssl.1.0.0.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin    550880 May  3 13:08 libssl.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 May  3 13:08 libssl.dylib -> libssl.1.0.0.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        18 Jan 29 16:15 libtermcap.dylib -> libncurses.6.dylib
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin     80356 Jan 29 16:21 libz.1.2.8.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 Jan 29 16:21 libz.1.dylib -> libz.1.2.8.dylib
-rw-r--r--   1 root  admin     93744 Jan 29 16:21 libz.a
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        16 Jan 29 16:21 libz.dylib -> libz.1.2.8.dylib
drwxr-xr-x  25 root  admin       850 Jun 17 00:03 pkgconfig
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  admin        17 Jan 29 16:15 terminfo -> ../share/terminfo
```

Is there any library that goes missing?

Comment: Maybe run  `ls -l /opt/local/lib | pbcopy` and click `edit` below your question and paste the directory listing.

Comment: Finally solved the problem: it's due to the implementation of 2 different C++ libraries in OSX. Adding -stdlib=libc++ solves the issue

Comment: Excellent! Well done - you can put it as the answer and accept it for all to see in future and also get the points. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the problem:

It's due to the implementation of 2 different C++ libraries in OSX. Adding -stdlib=libc++ solves the issue.